# Transaction log movement with no down time

Tags: transaction, log

If I were to create  a secondary file to handle log overflow and then delete the first file what will happen?

Comment: Presumably, this is about a *SQL Server* transaction log?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the question is about SQL Server:

You cannot actually delete a log file while the database is open.

You can create a secondary log file, wait for the primary log file VLFs to be freed up, either by transaction dumps or truncation (if running in simple recovery mode).

Once the new file is in use, you can shrink the old file to a very small size, however you cannot completely remove it without the database being taken offline.  Make sure you modify the original log file definition to prevent if from automatically growing.

Practice this on a non-production database until you know it works.

Comment: You may want to set AutoGrowth to NONE on the old log file as well.

Comment: yes, @MillhouseD - good point.